# Get top n most used tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys i am trying to get the most used tags from the database as show below:

```
+------------------------+
| post |       tags      |
+------------------------+
|  1   | ["php", "sql"]  |
|  2   | ["php", "html"] |
|  3   | ["css", "html"] |
|  4   |["php", "html5"] |
|  5   | ["php", "css"]  |
+------------------------+
```

I want to get the n most used tags in this table
I hoping you guys can help me set up a SQL Query, i cant find myself a way to start, thanks!

Comment: Is that what's currently stored in your database? Do you have nothing else? A tags table?

Comment: This is how i am using the tags only, the rest will be information about the post, like title, post body etc.

Comment: thats a bad way to store data you should consider normalizing the data.

Comment: I found it really easy to convert it as if it was a json object into php, also easy to work with when its already fetch.

Comment: Do you have another table that lists all the tags?

Comment: No i was hoping i could work with the data this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider re-designing your database to something like this:

```
Table: Posts
+=======================================================+
id    |    title    |    body    | user_id    |    etc..
+-------------------------------------------------------+

Table: Tags
+=====================+
id    |    name   
+---------------------+

Table: Post_tags
+======================+
post_id    |    tag_id
+----------------------+
```

Suppose you insert a new post with tags [php] and [html]. Then you will add the post to the `Posts` table, and add two rows to the `Post_tags` table, based on values stored in the `Tags` table:

```
Table: Posts
+========================================================+
id    |    title    |    body    | user_id    |    etc..
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1     |  New Post!  | Post body! |   2564     |    ...

Table: Tags
+======================+
id    |    name   
+----------------------+
  1   |    html
  2   |     php

Table: Post_tags
+======================+
post_id    |    tag_id
+----------------------+
 1         |   1
 1         |   2
```

Now, to get the most popular tags, you would just do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    tag_id,
    COUNT(tag_id)
FROM Post_tags
GROUP BY tag_id
```

which will give you a list of each tag and the number of times it has been used in a post.

Sorry, I know this doesn't exactly answer your question. If you really need to store the JSON style string of tags, you could do that as well in `Posts`, but to use that to get tag statistics is probably going to add far more complexity than necessary, and separating your data into relational tables is a much more effective way of doing things. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you I will take this into account and probably re-format my database, as you mention it seems to me more complex to do some tasks